# Convert outbound http call to https via apache

Tags: apache, ssl

We have an issue with our ageing WAS app server and the length of an ssl certificate it point blank will not support it and the third party will not change there certificate which is fair enough.

So is it possible to get our app server to make a http call to the third party but our apache web server to rewrite the request to https, the third party can then respond via https but our apache web server will rewrite this again back to http to make our app server happy?

Answer (score 2):

I would take mod_proxy into consideration. [take a look here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)

something like should should fit your needs:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    ... ssl and cert statements

    ProxyPass / http://new.domain.tld/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://new.domain.tld/
</VirtualHost>
```

and if you need it vice versa:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass / https://new.domain.tld/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://new.domain.tld/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Good answer - but I think the OP wants to initiate a http request and proxy to https.

Comment: then it should be just vice versa; 

`<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld
    
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass / https://new.domain.tld/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://new.domain.tld/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/myssl/public.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/myssl/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/myssl/chain-class2.pem
</VirtualHost>`